# Как использовать полученные данные JSON во ViewController?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, парсер

Я создал такой класс, и записываю туда полученные данные

```
class NewsObject {
    var pictureURL: String!
    var newsTitleJSON: String!
    var fullText: String!

    required init(json: JSON) {
        pictureURL = json["image"].stringValue
        newsTitleJSON = json["post_title"].stringValue
        fullText = json["full_text"].stringValue
    }
}
```

Получаю такие данные

```
{
    "posts": [
    {
    "id": "7",
    "post_title": "АСТАНА ТОЙҒА ДАЙЫН ОТЫР",
    "full_text": "Қала тұрғындары мен қонақтары әдемі мерекелердің бірі — елорда күнін қарсы алады. Ару Астана жаңа кейіпке енбек — ғимараттардың мерекеге орай безендірілген қасбеттері, жарқ-жұрқ еткен конструкциялар және шағын сәулетті пішіндер ерекше атмосфера орнатпақ, деп хабарлады www.24.kz.\r\n\r\nАлматы ауданындан.",
    "image": "/web/images/06/Астана-2.jpg",
    "image_title": "АСТАНА ТОЙҒА ДАЙЫН ОТЫР",
    "comment_count": "0",
    "comment_id": "0",
    "create_date": "123123",
    "modification_date": "1474848000",
    "authot_id": "1",
    "review": "84",
    "meta_desk": "АСТАНА ТОЙҒА ДАЙЫН ОТЫР",
    "meta_key": "АСТАНА ТОЙҒА ДАЙЫН ОТЫР",
    "is_release": "1",
    "menu_category_id": "17",
    "menu_category_name": "Ғылым-білім",
    "author_name": "Admin",
    "video": "",
    "image_id": null
    },
Функция получения данных

    func getData() {

    RestAPIManager.sharedInstance.getNews { (json: JSON) in

        if let results = json["posts"].array {
        for entry in results {
            self.newItems.append(NewsObject(json: entry))
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { })
        }
    }
}
```

Как теперь присвоить поле post_title в Label новости во ViewController?

Comment: У вас есть объект, в котором данные. Есть вью контроллер, в котором лейбл ждет эти данные. Так в чем может быть проблема? Передайте свой NewsObject в контроллер и заполните лейбл)

Comment: Вот именно что я делаю так let news = NewsObject() и потом передаю в Label так newsTitleLable.text = news.newsTitle а он мне пишет ошибку Missing arguments for parameter 'json' in call

Comment: Раставте брейкпоинты и посмотрите, как у вас парсится джейсон, что вы получаете на выходе и тд. У вас же после парсинга должен получится массив объектов, а не один ваш NewsObject. Посмотрите, что из себя представляет NewsObject, который вы передаете контроллеру

Comment: Если вы получаете данные с сервера в другом файле, а контроллер находится  в другом файле и вопрос стоит в том как достучаться до контроллера, а именно передать данные полученные с парсинга, то с этим отлично справляется делегат.

Comment: покажите сам контроллер